# Что надо знать, чтобы разработать собственный смартфон или SoC-компьютер?

Tags: железо, arm

У меня есть желание изучить компьютерную инженерию с целью создания своих компьютеров на SoC(ARM и x86-64).

Прошу описать весь "путь":

- То, что необходимо знать до начала
- То, что необходимо прочитать для получения опыта
- Портирование и запуск операционной системы(Linux)
- И др.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала стоит почитать чего то простенького по схемотехнике. Что бы мочь отличить конденсатор от резистора и понимать, для чего они нужны (тут конечно все зависит от того, насколько глубоко захочется "спуститься").

Потом почитать по элементарной логике (элементы и/или/не и теорию - булевы функции, правила деМоргана и тому подобное)

И можно взять например эту книгу - [[https://habrahabr.ru/post/259505/](Учебник](https://habrahabr.ru/post/259505/](%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA) Дэвида Харриса и Сары Харрис «Цифровая схемотехника и архитектура компьютера»).

Дальше будет понятнее.

Как бонус, рекомендовал бы найти подборку журналов Радио и там найти описание компьютера [Радио-86PK](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE_86%D0%A0%D0%9A). Сам "компьютер" и комплектующие сильно устарели, но думаю, его вполне можно переложить на современные рельсы. Там даже есть свои операционные системы под нее.

А вот с портированием линукса - это достаточно сложная задача. Если процессор будет стандартный, то нужно поискать компилятор под него (а может уже и есть готовая сборка, которую нужно будет сдобрить правильными драйверами). Если же нет, придется для начала сделать версию gcc или другой си компилятор для целевой платформы.